# Keyboard or piano or guitar which could be the best instrument to sturdy

Tags: guitar, piano, keyboard, digital-piano, self-learning

I love music.I am thinking to learn or practice a music instrument in my spare time.I already have some knowledge about "organ" .But it is just an elementary level. I love piano ,keyboard and guitar.I would like to learn one of above instruments properly with the help of a professional tutor. And I would like to self learn all other instruments by comparing with one which I learn from a professional tutor.Could any one suggest me a suitable instrument to learn from a professional (which would be more beneficial to self learn other instruments) ?

Comment: I've voted to close because this question doesn't have an objective answer. My opinion is that between piano, organ, and guitar, the piano will give the most transferable skills, mostly from reading music on separate clefs. But guitars are a lot easier to buy and practice on from a portability and noise standpoint, and are also not a bad choice.

Comment: @Thabo it might help to describe what kind of music you'd like to learn, and how - by ear or by reading music (might be swayed by the type of music). A question on Stack Exchange needs to have an object5ive factual answer so this current one at least needs to be re-phrased such that people can provide an objective answer - although I suspect that may be difficult for this quesiton.